# Where to find my custom content field within the Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have a field `CoverImage` in my `BlogPost` content definition, which I defined within the Content Definition menu in the admin control panel. I assume that whenever a `BlogPost` is rendered I can access it somewhere within `Model` from the associated alternate, e.g. via `Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.Field["CoverImage"]`, or something similar.

But in reality, I can't find any field within the `Model` that refers to custom fields at all whereas other fields such as `Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.Title` or `Model.ContentItem.BlogPostParts.Text` are available just fine. Can anyone explain?

[UPDATE]
Accesing `@Model.ContentItem.BlogPostPart.CoverImage.Value` gave an error: `'Orchard.Blogs.Models.BlogPostPart' does not contain a definition for 'CoverImage'`.

I can't find `CoverImage` in shape tracing:

[image: model]
.

Here's how I defined the `CoverImage` field within `Blog Post` content definition:

[image: field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jmgomez is right...as he says it will be:

> @{
>
> dynamic hey = (dynamic)Model;
> var yay =
> hey.ContentItem.BlogPost.CoverImage.MediaParts[0].MediaPart;
>
> }
>
> < img src='@yay.MediaUrl' />

As a little explanation for anyone interested... A default part is attached to a content item, where fields are attached to. It shows up as ContentPart but it is actually accessed using the name of your content type, so in this case BlogPost is the Content Type and CoverImage is the name of the field.

Comment: I was confused - it turns out there is both BlogPostPart and BlogPost in the model. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit confusing ^_^ Added a tiny explanation

Answer (score 2):

The "blahblah" that your are looking for is ContentItem, and in general for a part is:

```
  Model.ContentItem.NamePart.PropertyName
```

And for fields is

```
  Model.ContentItem.NamePart.NameField.Value
```

So in your case, should be something like:

```
  Model.ContentItem.BlogParts.CoverImage.Value
```